Interior french drain pipe installed upside down -- easiest fix?
In south central PA, I have water come into my basement during heavy rains for long periods.  I've had work done on the outside of the house near where the water tends to enter and, as part of that, they tarred a section of the found that was exposed (I was replacing an old front door stoop).  I hoped, as a bonus, that it would fix the water problem that I had occasionally.  Unfortunately, it did not.
My situation:  I have an unfinished area in my basement (about 10x8) with a sump pit in the corner.  There is a pvc pipe extending into the pit (which has some plexiglass over it for radon abatement/mitigation) a few inches below the concrete surface.  The length of the pipe goes along the front of the house and is about 20" from the edge of the basement cinder block wall.  The unfinished exterior cinder block walls are treated with drylock and I've never gotten water coming in through those walls.
What I've come to realize (after reading about interior french drains) looking at this pipe is that for it to truly be a French drain, the holes in it should be on the bottom of the gravel bed it is in (or I assume it is in b/c I'm not the original owner).  I'm confident it is in a gravel bed because I've put a snake camera ~10' down the pipe and can see gravel stones through the holes in the top of the pipe.  See pictures.
The water coming into the basement isn't TERRIBLE, but it's hard to say exactly how bad it is b/c I never let it get to its worst.  I'm always there with towels, shop vacs, and a transfer pump.  I recently tested running a sprinkler against the outside of the house continuously for about 6.5 hours.  I generated enough water to:

get a few small puddles on the inside in the unfinished area and just into the finished section, where I've now removed some of the 2x4 framing, panels and vapor barrier and added more drylock (this is directly under the new front door stoop).
could feel the difference in temperature between the lowest dry locked cinder blocks (about 2-2.5) and the highest (cooler to the touch on the lower ones)
could SEE water flowing into the sump well NOT from the pipe, but from underneath it where it enters the well.

I've taken pictures down the length of the pipe using a snake camera and shining a high-powered flashlight I've laid in there.  There is NO blockage.
I feel like the fundamental problem here is that the drain pipe wasn't installed with the holes pointed down and that the level of the water doesn't ever get high enough to enter the pipe from the holes in the top - the water pressure is relieved either by leaking under the pipe into the sump well (which is fine), or through gaps in the cinder block, or the interface between the concrete floor and cinder block as it flows over the footer.
Finally, for my question:  Would it relieve these problems if I just drilled down into the pipe from above and went just far enough down to put holes in the bottom of that drain pipe to turn it into a TRUE French drain?  Doing that would be pretty easy - I could estimate the first hole near the sump, then the next one down could be spotted down the length of the pipe as I see light coming in (just in case the pipe isn't perfectly 20" away along the length of the wall.   Then it would be a matter of plugging up those holes in the top.  Does this seem feasible?  If so, how many holes per foot would I need?
(You will see another pipe coming in from the right side in the picture of the sump well - don't worry about that, there's never been water over there even though THAT pipe appears upside down as well)






Hmm. Tiny pipe-crawling drilling robot.

You don't say how deep the pipe is buried, but one might infer that it is fairly shallow based on you saying it will be "easy" to drill through (I have my doubts about that...) I think your plan will work to improve the effectiveness of your existing pipe (and I don't see any reason to go through the trouble of plugging the upper holes), and you can prove that out by repeating your test. Whether or not it stops the seep...?

As long as the soffit of the pipe is below your slab, water should still infil through the holes even if they're on the top of the pipe.

pipe-crawling robot -- had the same thought.

@Jimmy Fix-it -- The top of the pipe is ~4 inches below the concrete.  The pipe is ~4" in diameter.

I probably should had added another question ... What IS this pipe if not for drainage?  It obviously is intended for water to flow into the sump well.
